# Is there a way to have a right fixed image not break the line on the left side?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to align images to the right side of the screen without having a line break on the other side in HTML/CSS? I have tried to figure this out, but the methods I tried (absolute position, not using float) either did not do anything, or made the element go away entirely. Could someone tell me how to accomplish this?

```
 <body>
  <p class="title"><img src="pkd.png" class="logo"></p>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <div class="wrap">
    stuff on here:
    <a href="postboard.html" class="rd"><img src="bb.png"></a>
    <a href="about.html" class="rd"><img src="ab.png"></a>
    <a href="https://forms.gle/YJp3o7qQxRt2gKbE6" class="rd"><img src="rb.png"></a>
    </div>
    <p>Welcome to PolyKD! This site is still under construction , so there's not much yet .</p>
    <p> But what there is you can find over to your right .</p>
    <p>Have a nice day! <img src="pippin.png"></p>
  </body>
```

Looks like:
[This.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z88cq.png)

I want it to look like: [This.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re4Co.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to write questions that best enable the community to provide helpful assistance.  Can you provide an [mcve] that includes your CSS?  That will make it much easier for visitors to the page to offer solutions to your problem.  FWIW, if you want the "stuff on here" menu to remain fixed in that position as the users scrolls you might use `position: fixed`; otherwise, I'd recommend reading up on how to do CSS layout using `grid` and `flex`-- absolute positioning and floats are special-case only.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: You could use positioning and use `position: absolute` on the image. Did you try something like this?

Comment: Yes, I have. I'll try Alexander's method and get back to you soon. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with HTML, so I do not know how to rework the problem into an MRE, but I can provide my CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use positioning,

```
<body>
<p class="title">
    <img src="pkd.png" class="logo">
</p>
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<div class="wrap">
    stuff on here:
    <a href="postboard.html" class="rd"><img src="bb.png"></a>
    <a href="about.html" class="rd"><img src="ab.png"></a>
    <a href="https://forms.gle/YJp3o7qQxRt2gKbE6" class="rd"><img src="rb.png"></a>
</div>
<div style="position:relative">
    <p>Welcome to PolyKD! This site is still under construction , so there's not much yet .</p>
    <p> But what there is you can find over to your right .</p>
    <p>Have a nice day!</p>
    <img src="pippin.png" style="position:absolute; right:0;">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sadly, it did not work. The gap is still there. And my "pippin.png" emote moved the far right side.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting divs should help:

```
<p class="title"><img src="pkd.png" class="logo"></p>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <div>
    <div align=left width="80%" style="float:left">
        <p>Welcome to PolyKD! This site is still under construction , so there's not much yet .</p>
        <p> But what there is you can find over to your right .</p>
        <p>Have a nice day! <img src="pippin.png"></p>
    </div>
        <div align=right class="wrap" width="20%" style="float:right">
        stuff on here:<br/>
        <a href="postboard.html" class="rd"><img src="bb.png"></a><br/>
        <a href="about.html" class="rd"><img src="ab.png"></a><br/>
        <a href="https://forms.gle/YJp3o7qQxRt2gKbE6" class="rd"><img src="rb.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ah, it worked, but the borders I placed on the sides (in my css sheet, which I will happily provide,) are gone and the positioning of the box has been moved to the bottom.

Comment: ya sure we can try